# Modular Inverse and BigInteger division

Tags: java, algorithm

I've been working on the problem of calculating the modular inverse of an large integer i.e. a^-1 mod n.  and have been using BigInteger's built in function modInverse to check my work.

I've coded the algorithm as shown in The Handbook of Applied Cryptography by Menezes, et al.  Unfortunately for me, I do not get the correct outcome for all integers.

My thinking is that the line q = a.divide(b) is my problem as the divide function is not well documented (IMO)(my code suffers similarly).  Does BigInteger.divide(val) round or truncate?  My assumption is truncation since the docs say that it mimics int's behavior.  Any other insights are appreciated.

This is the code that I have been working with:

```
private static BigInteger modInverse(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) throws ArithmeticException {
    //trivial case: b = 0 => a^-1 = 1
    if (b.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    //all other cases
    BigInteger x2 = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger x1 = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger y2 = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger y1 = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger x, y, q, r;
    while (b.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 1) {
        q = a.divide(b);
        r = a.subtract(q.multiply(b));
        x = x2.subtract(q.multiply(x1));
        y = y2.subtract(q.multiply(y1));
        a = b;
        b = r;
        x2 = x1;
        x1 = x;
        y2 = y1;
        y1 = y;
    }
    if (!a.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
        throw new ArithmeticException("a and n are not coprime");
    return x2;
}
```

An example of input that is yielding incorrect input is:
a: 123456789
b: 2^809 - 1

An example of input that is yielding expected results is:
a: 123456789
b: 2^807 - 1

Comment: Can you give example of input that gets the wrong output?

Comment: Are you sure that the first input yields wrong answer? For both your inputs, I get that a*modInverse(a,b) mod b equals 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `return x2;` to `return y2;` and your routine will give the correct answer.

**Edit**, this answer is no longer valid, as the top poster changed his code.

Comment: I do see that I had a problem with the code, swapping a and b in certain cases was causing the result to be in y2 rather than x2.  But the code as it is now still will not work for the case that I added.

Comment: When I tested earlier today, changing x2 to y2 worked as long as I was calling your function with a < b, expecting to get a^{-1} mod b.

Comment: When I call your function (as it is given in the question) with your first input, I get -8588766....8597578, which multiplied by a and taking modulo b gives 1. This is correct output, as far as I can see.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It hadn't occurred to me that mine wasn't incorrect but merely different than BigInteger.  Such is learning.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how integer division is specified in the Java Language Specification:

> #### [JLS 15.17.2 Division Operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.17.2)
>
> **Integer division rounds toward 0.** That is, the quotient produced for operands `n` and `d` that are integers after binary numeric promotion is an integer value `q` whose magnitude is as large as possible while satisfying `|d·q|<=|n|`; moreover, `q` is positive when `|n|>=|d|` and `n` and `d` have the same sign, but `q` is negative when `|n|>=|d|` and `n` and `d` have opposite signs.

Comment: The above link doesn't seem to work any more.  But from it I was able to browse to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work you need to save the original value of the modulus, you can create at the begining: BigInteger m = b; 
Then when you obtain the final result in x2, to avoid the negative values that can result from the Euclidean Algorithm, compute: x2.add(m) which will be the multiplicative inverse of the BigInteger a, mod(b), according to your code.